# Xcode doesn't load image from CUICatalog

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When running my code I get two errors:

> CUICatalog: Invalid asset name supplied:

and

> "Could not load the "" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.blahblah.blahblah""

Comment: Open the xib, check all the occurrences of UI elements where you could put an UIImage, and check the name with the one in .assets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case one UIBarButtonItem has `Unknown image` in storyboard.

[image]